# How to run a function every 10 seconds?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I know this question has been asked quite a few times on SO, but none of them have been able to fix my problem. **I want to call a function every 10 seconds using threads**.

I have a function that does frame processing. I want to be **able to grab a frame after every 10 seconds and then process it**. My research showed that it would be best to use threads for that purpose, and, as I need to perform it after a specific period of time, I would also require a timer control.

I am not able to figure out how can use threading and timers together. Moreover, I have tried using a `BackgroundWorker` control which, while processing, hangs up my app badly. I have also tried using a timer control and tried calling the function every 10 seconds, but in that case, if the process exceeds 10 seconds that might cause some problems.

Any examples or source code that could show me how to call a function every 10 seconds using threading will be really appreciated.

Comment: Look at timers, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Well what do you *want* to happen if it takes more than 10 seconds? What exactly do you mean by "might cause some problem"? Does your call need to execute in the UI thread?

Comment: I think the code you are using would be extremely helpful in understanding your problem and how to solve it

Comment: @ Jon Skeet: well If it takes more than 10 secs i want it to complete the processing and then move to next frame for processing..and by problem i mean it can hang the app..yes I need to do more processing on UI thread once frame is processed..

Answer (score 12):

You don't necessarily need threads. You can use await/async:

```
public async Task DoSomethingEveryTenSeconds()
{
   while (true)
   {
      var delayTask = Task.Delay(10000);
      DoSomething();
      await delayTask; // wait until at least 10s elapsed since delayTask created
   }
}
```

In this example, the returned task will never finish; to fix that you need to use some other condition instead of `true`.

In an application with a GUI, this will execute DoSomething on the UI thread via the  message loop, like any other event (like a button click handler). If there is no GUI, it will run on a thread pool thread.

Comment: This will *wait* 10 secs between "doing something", not "execute every 10 secs". Especially if that DoSomething takes a few seconds this may not be exactly what the OP wants. Or this may be good enough, hard to say.

Comment: @HansKesting: Good point; I have indeed assumed that the time taken to execute `DoSomething` is negligible.

Comment: To make this work according to the requirements you should create the `Task.Delay` task before invoking the `DoSomething`, and `await` the task afterwards.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias nice idea, fixed

Comment: It's an idea stolen from a Stephen Cleary's answer in another question somewhere. :-)

Answer (score 8):

Use **[System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)**

```
private Timer timer1; 
public void InitTimer()
{
    timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Interval = 10000; // in miliseconds
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    yourfunctionhere();
}
```

Comment: Related article: [Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx#S4)

Answer (score 0):

In a Windows Forms application, add a timer from Visual Studio's ToolBox, double-click it under the Designer view, and put the functionality that you want to be executed every X seconds in the function that appears. Be sure to enable the Timer in the properties view; there you can also change your interval (in milliseconds).

Answer (score -1):

**You can use this code if you want to run code for 10 second then stop it**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Timers;
namespace Tdo
{
    class Program
    {
      public static bool k=true;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Timer q = new Timer(10000);
            q.Elapsed += Q_Elapsed;
            q.Start();
            while(k)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void Q_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            StopTheCode(ref k);
        }

        public static void StopTheCode(ref  bool flag)
        {
            flag= false;   
        }            

    }
}
```

**Here is simply  write the Date time of now for 10 second and when timer  elapsed it set the flag = false and the while stop but be aware those 10 second will depend on your device GHz mean  number of execution of the instruction per second will vary**